# Convergence of some sums of complex functions

Tags: power-series, polylogarithm, formal-power-series

In the context of the probability theory of rare events i found myself dealing with these series of complex functions:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+n)^{-k}z^{n^2}\\$ with z Complex and k Real.
2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+n)^{-k}e^{\Lambda n\sqrt{\ln{z}}}$ with z Complex, k Real and $\Lambda$ complex parameter.
3. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+n)^{-k}e^{\Lambda n\sqrt{\ln{z}}+n^2\ln{z}}$ with k and $\Lambda$ as above.

With my supervisor we have found a close analogy of these series with Polylog functions, which converge for z<1. I need to put this in a more rigorous fashion because we need an integral representation for this functions to discuss the values of the parameters, but something is missing. No simple test of convergence seems to work at least to prove the absolute convergence.

Comment: Is $k$ a positive real, or any real? I think it should be easy if $k>1$, which leads me to assume that this is not the case.

Comment: The ratio test quickly establishes that (1) converges absolutely for $|z|<1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$. As for (2) and (3), since $\Lambda$ is complex, are you using a specific branch of $\sqrt{\ln z}$?

Comment: k could be any real. The branch of $\sqrt\ln{z}$ and the value of k must be chosen to have a solution for the equation $Q(z)'/Q(z)=\rho+1$ where Q is one of the above series and $\rho$ any real.